# Get a value from a string with If condition

Tags: apex, string, if

I am trying to obtain a value from a string if something is true in the string, example:
I have the following String

```
   String str1 = "{\n\"test1\": \"132456789\",\n\"test2\": \"123123123\",\n\"First\": \"Manuel\",\n\"Last\": \"Rodriguez\"\n\}"
```

What I want is, if within the str1 comes the test1 property, then I want to create a variable and give it the value that test1 has, which in this case would be 132456789.

For the condition I did this:

```
     String varTest = (str1.contains('test1')) ? [here should come the value 132456789, It's what I don't know how] : [if it doesn't come then a ''];
```

I thought maybe with a split but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your input looks close to being JSON (with extra escaping and double quotes that you'd need to deal with first). Try to see if you can get JSON (or modify what you have to make it valid JSON). From there, deserialization and testing for/extracting a value would be trivial.

Comment: Yes it worked, I put the solution below, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution and it worked for me:

```
String String0 = null;
String String1 = '{\n\"test1\": \"132456789\",\n\"test2\": \"123123123\",\n\"First\": \"Manuel\",\n\"Last\": \"Rodriguez\"}'; 
String String2 = '[' + String1 + ']';
            if (String0 == null) {
                if (String2.contains('test1')) {
                    Map<String, Object> valuesMap = new Map<String, Object>();
                    for(Object obj : (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(String2)){
                        //convert values to map
                        Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)obj;
                        valuesMap.putAll(data);
                    }
                    String0 = String.valueof(valuesMap.get('test1'));
                }else{
                    String0 = ''; 
                }
            }
System.debug('String0: ' + String0); // String0: 123456789
```